# Unable to connect to development server in React Native for Android

Tags: android, react-native, adb

I am trying to open my react-native app on an emulator, but I am continuously facing the red screen error after the initial load.

Here are few of my observations --

1. When I run `react-native run-android` from my project root directory, the adb is running on port 8081. Refer the screenshot.
   [image]
2. When the app first launches, it shows the default screen properly. Refer screenshot below.[image]
3. Although it asks to edit the index.android.js, I had already added code in that file. **I am not sure why it is not loading the screen on the first load.** Refer screenshot below.[image]
4. When I reload this screen by double tapping 'R' on my keyboard, I see the red-screen error saying that the development server could not be connected.
5. I changed the default port 8081 to some other port number in the file `server.js` and gave the same port number and my machine's IP address in Developer Menu on the device.

**After doing all the above steps, still I am getting the red-screen error that development server could not be connected.**
I am sure I am missing some silly thing, which I need to connect these dots and make the app running.
Please help me. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:**

After running `react-native start`, system gets stuck at this step and nothing happens.[image]

Comment: Below answer solved my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48782661/1533666

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have ran `react-native start`
If so, you can try running `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, for showing up on this post after a long time! I am getting the error -- `js server not recognized continuing with build` whenever I am running `react-native run-android`. Also I followed your steps and whenever I run the command `react-native start` with or without resetting cache, system stays still after the step `Loading dependency graph, done` and nothing happens after that. Please refer to the snapshot added in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in your AndroidManifest if you're using android-28 and above.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I misconfigured the `network_security_config.xml` file which I added to the application tag in the manifest using `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`, according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config).

In android-28 and above, `android:usesCleartextTraffic` is disabled by default (thanks @MiguelPanelo), which means localhost gets blocked when using that config file. When I removed that file, it worked. However, upon further inspection I found that I could just add another `<domain-config>` tag for localhost along with my other tags which I put in for security purposes, like so:

```
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
</domain-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you did not get any error in the server while changing the code in **index.android.js.**
Because the error you might have got in the server might cause the server to break connection internally. so,

- Try to close the server.
- run
  `react-native start --reset-cache`
- reload the app.

It might solve your problem.
Hope it Helps.

Comment: Sorry, for showing up on this post so after a long time!
I am getting the error -- `js server not recognized continuing with build` whenever I am running `react-native run-android`.
Also I followed your steps and whenever I run the command `react-native start` with or without resetting cache, system stays still after the step `Loading dependency graph, done` and nothing happens after that. Please refer to the snapshot added in the question.