# React-Native for Android: Could not connect to development server

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am setting up react native android for existing project. I followed instruction from [Official getting started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) page. And I am able to open the app in in emulator when I run `react-native run-android`. The app is running perfectly.
But the issue is, when I reload it using double clicking `R` key, it throws error `Could not connect to development server`.

[image]

Getting this error on Emulator and real device both

Solutions I have tried:

1. Running real device and Macbook on same wifi.
2. Setting macbook's IP address & port in Android device/Emulator in `Dev Setting -> Debug server host & port for device`
3. Running `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Still no luck.

When I open developer option using `CMD + D` and clicks on `Debug JS Remotely`, it throws different error:
`Unable to connect to remote debugger. CLEARTEXT communication to 192.x.x.x not permitted by network security policy.`

In some cases it is showing "Connecting to remote debugger", but it is stuck there. 
[image]

Comment: Just curious, have you tried to do this on different emulators?

Comment: I tried on Emulator Google Pixel 3, when it did not work. I tried on real device as well. But had the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer fixed my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53158627/2630184

Seems like it was issue with `Cleartext` on Android Pie as I also mentioned this in question that cleartext error is getting displayed while clicking on `Debug js remotely`.

Adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml, fixed this issue for me.

```xml
<application
    android:name="com.example.app"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Comment: Please note that this can be a security issue and android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" should only be used in AndroidManifest.xml for debug purposes. In production, all information should be transferred via HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check if your device has an Internet connection. If Wi-Fi symbol has a cross with it, it means that there were some trouble with connection between MacOS and emulator. For me last time helped next steps:

1) Go to *Mac > System preferences > Network > Advanced... > DNS*.

2) Click to the *+* to add new DNS server.

3) Add 8.8.8.8 there.

4) Close your emulator and open it again. Check the connection and if the build is working

Comment: Hi, thanks. I did that change. Still not working. Same error. After sometime it is showing blank screen with green top bar "Connecting to to remote debugger". Not it is stuck there. This happened before as well.

Comment: I've posted the answer: Adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml fixed the issue.