# When i start the React Native Project this error always comes

Tags: react-native

[image]

I am having the same error again and again after when i start the React Native Project!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something with the emulator. Close all emulators that you have running, open the Taskmanager and under Processes look for adb.exe and kill all processes that are named like that.

After that run the emulator again and then try to start your project again.

Comment: I killed all the processes of adb.exe but this error error did not go :(

Comment: maybe take a look into this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064283/could-not-connect-to-react-native-development-server-on-android

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `local.properties` file
2. Add
   `sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk` following inside `local.properties` file that you created
3. Then add your `local.properties` file inside android folder.
4. Try `react-native run-android`

Comment: You mean to say make file on notepad which name is local.properties and in that i file add sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk in the file and add local.properties file in sdk folder ?

Comment: Not in sdk folder, but ANDROID FOLDER