# Android Studio Refuses to Connect to React Native Server

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Hi I'm trying to get the basic [React Native tutorial here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) set up, under the CLI quickstart tab, but I keep running into issues. Please note that I'm trying to run this on an emulator.

Here are the specifics of my set up:

- Mac OS: Mojave  10.14.5
- Node:           14.15.5
- npx:            6.14.11
- gem:            3.2.3
- watchman:       4.9.0
- Android Studio: 3.5.3
- JRE:            1.8

Running the command "react-native start" opens up Metro, shows this, but it never says "Done."

[image: Metro in terminal not showing "done"]

Running the command "npx react-native run android" causes this message on the terminal

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 25s
27 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 22 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
adb: error: cannot bind listener: Operation not permitted
warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": Command failed: /Users/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity }
```

On the emulator, this is what I see

[image: Android Emulator Error]

I've hit the reload button, and gotten this screen on the emulator
[image]

[then followed instructions detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064283/could-not-connect-to-react-native-development-server-on-android) and set up the IP address but still no luck. I've tried using the command "react-native run android" and it gives the same results as above.

This is the most basic project I can set up and I've followed the instructions listed on the tutorial to the letter multiple times with many fresh projects. I'm really not sure what more I can do or where I could've messed up. I've seen similar issues posted on other forums but they've all been closed without proper resolution. I've tried using "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081" as commonly suggested and it changed nothing.

iOS gives a separate issue entirely but I'll probably make that into a separate question. Does anyone how I can resolve this? What could the issue be here? It seems to be a common enough problem but there's no single agreed solution. Running the app directly in Android Studio results in the same issues too.

I've been trying to make this work for about two weeks now so I appreciate any help people can offer. Thanks.

Comment: did you try to change the ip from 10.0.2.2:8081 into 10.0.1.1:8081 ?

Comment: No I haven't since I thought the 10.0.1.1 IP was just an example. If anything it should be 10.0.2.2, right?